# Is it possible to control server via CGI?

Tags: cgi

Is it possible to control server via CGI? For example, run the windowns update of the server, open some application of the server, of shutdown the server computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends which server, and what access rights the CGI owner has there. If you can find (or code) a right executable, you can do anything you have permission for. CGI is just a very specific protocol by which web server passes data to and from external executables.

For example, if you're renting a shared Linux host, you will not be able to shut down the computer (because you will not have a permission to do so); and you will not be able to update Windows (because, what Windows?).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. CGI executes an EXE on the server so you can program it to do everything you want